# Pandas count number of equal values per row in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I work with this `df`:

```
A   B   C   D
1   1   2   3
2   1   3   4
3   3   3   3
```

I want to add column `E` that holds the number of equal values in columns `A`-`D` by row.
Expected output:

```
A   B   C   D   E
1   1   2   3   2
2   1   3   4   0
3   3   3   3   4
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thanks!

Comment: What happens when multiple columns in a row have equal values . If a row has for example 3,3,2,2 <- do you still expect the result to be 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use custom lambda function with [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with `keep=False` for all dupes and count `True`s by `sum`:

```
df['E'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.duplicated(keep=False).sum(), axis=1)
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E
0  1  1  2  3  2
1  2  1  3  4  0
2  3  3  3  3  4
```

If need specify columns names:

```
df['E'] = df.loc[:, 'A':'D'].apply(lambda x: x.duplicated(keep=False).sum(), axis=1)
```